# Storing data in Solr core at different location based on environment variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, solr

I am working on Java Spring Boot web application. I am storing some data in Solr. I have many different Solr Cores in root directory, which is defined in `application.properties`. My application works just fine. Now I need to run the application as docker container with given environment variables. One of these variables would indicate, where to store some data from one particular Solr Core, eg. `Core1`. This core would be always the same one, just the locations would be different.

In practice, I have some data, that I work with and isn't stored anywhere. This data is divided into 10 different "types" of data. For example I'm storing `Person` objects, but I have 10 different nationalities. Now I need to save it to solr core `Core1`, but I want to divide it by these nationalities, so I would have 10 different folders with data. This processed data I want to export somewhere through some kind of controller, let's say. As of yet, I am not sure, if it would be better to store independently and export the data itself, or the entire Core with that data in it. Not sure if one or the other is better or even feasible.

I'm having hard time figuring out how to configure Solr in a way, that it would store data in different folder based on this given environment variable.

I tried to define `dataDir` property in `core.properties` file of my `Core1` Solr Core like this:
`dataDir=${SOLR_DATA}/data` and then defined the `${SOLR_DATA}` variable as environment variable in Windows, even restarded PC, but still my Spring Boot application crashes with error that there is no system variable with this name.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble seeing the connection here - Solr runs by itself and your Spring Boot application runs by itself. Which part is having trouble seeing the environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that my question was pretty out of place and my problem was solved in completely different way. We created Docker container and passed path to external SolrCore as a parameter.